# Website showing empty spaces on the right side in android phones

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-website

My website works fine in iOS and in browsers, however it shows empty space in android phones on the right. Tried many css edits but this doesn't seen to go away.

[www.allorganik.in](http://www.allorganik.in)

Can someone help with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Added this code in CSS and everything got fixed.

/*viewport settings for android*/

html { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; !important; }
body { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; !important; }

Thanks!